# Get averages of specific columns in a table using sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a basic sqlite table with about 10 columns. The first column is a text name, while the rest are just integers. I was hoping to form a new table that has one row for each of the distinct values in the first row, and every other column be an average of all the instances of that column. For example if I have the below table:

```
foo  1  3  5
bar  3  4  1
edd  2  1  3
bar  1  4  2
foo  1  1  3
```

Then I would want to create a new table with three rows (foo, bar, edd), and the row would have the average of each column for those rows. Is this possible using sqlite?

```
foo  1  2  4
bar  2  2.5 1.5
edd  2  1  3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
select col1, avg(col2), avg(col3), avg(col4)
from mytable
group by col1
```